# Code Craft Angular 4 tutorial on Plunker encounters Unexpected token <, what's the issue?

Tags: angular, typescript, unexpected-token

I am following this online tutorial by [Code Craft](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/quickstart/first-app/) to learn Angular 4, however, the tutorial code that it provides cannot be ran. From the console, it has the following errors:

```
run.plnkr.co/:15 Error: (SystemJS) Unexpected token <
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
        at eval (<anonymous>)
        at ZoneDelegate.invoke (https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.7.4?main=browser:242:26)
        at Zone.run (https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.7.4?main=browser:113:43)
        at https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.7.4?main=browser:520:57
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.7.4?main=browser:275:35)
    Evaluating http://run.plnkr.co/jcyQ8TmdjBFrmoqI/script.ts
    Error loading http://run.plnkr.co/jcyQ8TmdjBFrmoqI/script.ts
        at eval (<anonymous>)
        at ZoneDelegate.invoke (https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.7.4?main=browser:242:26)
        at Zone.run (https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.7.4?main=browser:113:43)
        at https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.7.4?main=browser:520:57
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.7.4?main=browser:275:35)
    Evaluating http://run.plnkr.co/jcyQ8TmdjBFrmoqI/script.ts
    Error loading http://run.plnkr.co/jcyQ8TmdjBFrmoqI/script.ts
```

Here is the [Plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/X1PpIFrTgBZb22YsvLeo?p=preview), please help. Thank you.

GJ

Comment: the plunker link you posted works fine, I dont see errors..

Comment: Same as @AhmedMusallam, seems fine... are you still getting the errors?